# Cannot read Flutter dependency from an Azure Devops repo on a Mac (works on a PC)

Tags: git, flutter, azure-devops

I have a flutter project that has a dependency on another flutter library which it fetches from an Azure Devops repository.

In the `pubspec.yaml` I have the line :-

```
dependencies:
     my_base_widgets:
        git: https://myrepo.visualstudio.com/myreponame/_git/My_Library
```

Running `flutter pub get` works perfectly in Android Studio and VSCode on a PC.

But on a Mac I get the fatal error

> Could not read Username for 'https://myrepo.visualstudio.com' : device not configured

I've been around the houses trying to figure out why this is failing on a mac. Can anyone help with what's missing in my configuration?

Comment: Did you try out below answer, any updates?

Comment: I didn't find a viable solution to this problem and had spend so much time on it that I just reincorporated the library code into my source. I'll recreate the library and try to jump this hurdle again when I have to

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of ways of addressing this problem:

- One of the easiest is to move to using ssh authentication rather than
  https.
- You could hardcode the credentials for github into your local git
  repository, as described in the [gitcredentials](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials) documentation.
- You could configure an appropriate helper application. One may
  already be configured, but git may simply not be able to find it. The
  [gitcredentials](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials) man page has information on this option as well.

There is a similar error ticket in the community, you can refer to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41197696/fatal-could-not-read-username-for-visualstudio-com-device-not-configured) and check if it is working for you.